# Variable value changing in between functions?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

11When I run one function, at the end, the variable 'hangarDone' is changed to 'True' (its is false at the start) but when I run the morrigan function it prints as false.

```
def morrigan():
    print ('Hang2',hangarDone)
    hangar()

def hangar():
    [There is content here but nothing happens with hangarDone]
    hangarDone = 'True'
    save()
    print ('Hang1',hangarDone)
    morrigan()
```

Output:

```
Hang2 False
Hang1 True
Hang2 False
```

Comment: Please ignore the infinite loop, in the real code it is not there,

Comment: you create a local variable with the same name as a global, if you want to change the global variable you need to use the `global` statement.